# How to add new item into IEnumerable<model> list without deleting the items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ajaxq

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string[] departments)
    {
        IEnumerable<Batch> batchList = Enumerable.Empty<Batch>();
        try
        {
            string a;
            for (int i = 0; i < departments.Length; i++)
            {
                a = departments[i];
                batchList = batchList.Concat(obj.Batches.Where(x => x.Department_Id == a));
            }
            return Json(batchList);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(null);
        }
    }
```

I am sending AjaxMethod() an array with two indexes departments[0]="BSCS" and departments[1]="BSIT"
And i am using concat method to append IEnumerable list when when for loop runs the 2nd time, it overwrites the result of departments[0] and it concatinates departments[1] with departments[1]
I want this output:
bscs-f13
bscs-f14
bscs-f15
bsit-f13
bsit-f14
bsit-f15
But the actual output is:
bsit-f13
bsit-f14
bsit-f15
bsit-f13
bsit-f14
bsit-f15

Comment: You are building up a list of objects, not reading an existing list. So use a `List<Batch>` and `Add()` instead of `IEnumerable<Batch>` and `Concat()`

Comment: i tried it but then it shows the error that cannot convert from iqueryable to batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq functions are [pure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750533/why-are-pure-functions-called-pure) so concatenation allocates each loop new memory.  You can simply iterate the `departments` argument.

```
batchList = departments.SelectMany(d=>obj.Batches.Where(x => x.Department_Id == d));
```